# Getting This Error :- Error: Invalid Data

Tags: apex

> Error :- **Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your data.**
>
> Apex trigger UpdatePaymentDetails caused an unexpected exception, contact
> your administrator:  UpdatePaymentDetails: execution of AfterUpdate caused by:  System.StringException:  Invalid id: Foundation:

Payment_Details__c is a child object of Payment_Plan__c in Payment_Details__c, Foundation_Amount_Due is to be updated based on change in Payment_Milestone__c picklist field to 'Foundation' in Payment_Plan__c

```
trigger UpdatePaymentDetails on Payment_Plan__c (after update) {
    Set <Id> PPIds = new Set <Id>();
    For (Payment_Plan__c P : Trigger.New){ 
        If ( P.Payment_Milestone__c != Null ){
            PPIds.add(P.Payment_Milestone__c);
        }  
    }


    Map<ID,Payment_Details__c> ExistPayDetMap = New Map<ID,Payment_Details__c>(
       [Select ID,Payment_Plan__c ,Payment_Plan__r.Payment_Milestone__c,
       Payment_Plan__r.Unit_Name__r.Base_Apartment_Cost__c, Booking_Amount_Due__c ,
       Foundation_Amount_Due__c from Payment_Details__c WHERE ID IN : PPids]);


    for(Payment_Plan__c p : Trigger.New){
        Payment_Details__c PD =  ExistPayDetMap.get(p.id);
        If ((p.Payment_Milestone__c == 'Foundation') && (PD.Foundation_Amount_Due__c == Null))
            PD.Foundation_Amount_Due__c = 0.10 * PD.Payment_Plan__r.Unit_Name__r.Base_Apartment_Cost__c;
    }

        Update ExistPayDetMap.values();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

according to your Code, it seems that Payment_Milestone__c is referencing field and you are comparing `p.Payment_Milestone__c == 'Foundation'`. so this is the error to compare a referencing field with String that is invalid Id.

Answer (score 1):

`p.Payment_Milestone__c` is an ID (reference) field according to the error, not a picklist field like it says in the question.  When you use the `==` operator on operands of two different types, the compiler will implicitly convert the right operand to the type of the left operand.  In your case, the compiled expression behaves like `p.Payment_Milestone__c == (ID)'Foundation'`.  Because strings can be implicitly converted to IDs, this is not a compilation error - however, during execution the ID conversion will check that the string being converted is a valid 15 or 18 character ID, which "Foundation" is not, which throws the error.

Most likely, either `Payment_Milestone__c` is not the correct field, or you need to reference one of the fields on the object it references, e.g. `p.Payment_Milestone__r.Name`.

If `Payment_Milestone__c` is actually a picklist field, then `PPIds.add(p.Payment_Milestone__c)` will throw the same error if the value of `p.Payment_Milestone__c` is "Foundation."  In this case, you probably meant `PPIds.add(p.ID)`.

Comment: Got it to reference by Name ie changed from Payment_Details__c PD =  ExistPayDetMap.get(p.id) to PD =  ExistPayDetMap.get(p.name). Also made the following change ie  removed the If condition just to check  // If ((p.Payment_Milestone__c == 'Foundation') && (PD.Foundation_Amount_Due__c == Null))
The error still persists

Comment: @RajivV.Subramanian OK, try putting a try-catch block around your code and use the catch block to write the line number to the debug log, then update your code to indicate which line threw the exception.  That said, I actually think that your line `PPIds.add(p.Payment_Milestone__c)` may be where the problem is - if `Payment_Milestone__c` is a picklist field and its value is `Foundation`, it will throw the same error.  Did you mean `PPIds.add(p.ID)`?